# A finite axiomatization for intuitionistic implicational logic.

Tags: axioms, intuitionistic-logic

I know that someone once gave a finite axiomatization for tautologies of classical propositional logic whose only connective is implication, but is there a finite axiomatization for tautologies of intuitionistic propositional logic whose only connective is implication? If so, can someone exhibit a finite list of axioms?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms

Comment: I don’t quite understand what you mean by “where the only connective is implication”. Just the implicational fragment of the logic? Or an axiomatization of the full logic where only that connective appears? (It would seem in the latter case that you are forgetting the negation connective.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Just the implicational fragment of the logic.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen No negation or falsity operator.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Hilbert-style_calculus for a finite set of **axiom schemas** for intuitionistic logic which will also work for the implicational fragment if you throw out the schemas involving connectives other than $\to$. Note that it is not a finite axiomatisation. To get a finite axiomatisation, you need to allow a rule of substitution, so that individual axioms with propositional variables can stand in for the schemas.

Comment: @RobArthan So, just the axiom schemas $(P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P))$ and $((P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R)) \rightarrow ((P \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow (P \rightarrow R)))$ will suffice for the implicational fragment? What is the proof?

Comment: The proof goes via [cut elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem), which shows that any theorem of intuitionistic propositional logic containing no connectives other than $\to$ can be proved without using rules that involve the other connectives. You also need to do some fiddling around to show the equivalence between the Hilbert-style system and the Gentzen-style system.